# Change MouseLeave animation when Grid is clicked

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

In my WPF appliction, I have a partially visible grid at the bottom of the visible space. When you mouseover it, it slides up and everything in the grid is visible. When the mouse leaves the grid, it slides back down. There are Combo and TextBoxes in the grid that will contain info and be able to be updated by the user.

How do I make it so that if I click anywhere in the grid, the MouseLeave animation no longer goes off (the grid stays up even you if your mouse leaves)?

I have implemented my animation 2 different ways in an attempt to get it to behave the way I want, but no luck so far.

Implementation 1:

```
`<Grid x:Name="PopupAnimation" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="30">
            <Grid.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="MouseOn">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="30" To="90" Duration="0:0:.15"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="MouseOff">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="90" To="30" Duration="0:0:0.15"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseOff" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </Grid.Triggers>
```

`

Implementation 2:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Name="MouseOn">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="30" To="90" Duration="0:0:.15"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Name="MouseOff">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="90" To="30" Duration="0:0:0.15"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
     </Grid>
```

Are either of these heading down the right road? How do I disable (and enable) an animation?

Comment: If there's nothing in the Grid that is user actionable once it's shown. A quickie thing you could do is just on click event of the grid just do a bool toggle to the IsHitTestVisible property on the parent Grid showing so it would just ignore any mouse events if clicked and IsHitTestVisible="false" which would nullify any of those IsMouseOver triggers and their actions.

Comment: @ChrisW. Unfortunately there are user actionable parts in the grid (comboboxes and whatnot). I'm hoping to make it a bit easier for the user to both quickly view info (mouse over) and edit it (once clicked, stay up until a button says go down). Will edit that into the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I make it so that if I click anywhere in the grid, the MouseLeave animation no longer goes off (the grid stays up even you if your mouse leaves)?

Don't execute the up and down movement by style, instead subscribe to the all events in question, and with the events of `mouse enter` and `mouse leave` run the storyboards in code-behind.

Then in the final event, in code behind grid click event, set a Boolean flag which will be read by the `mouse leave` event and allow it to not execute the storyboard.

---

Here is code I have to move a window in/out in codebehind to give you an idea about the storyboards:

```
if (moveRight)
{
   (Resources["MoveToOpen"] as Storyboard)?.Begin(this, false);
   (Resources["FlipArrowClose"] as Storyboard)?.Begin(this, false);
}
else
{ 
   if (closeWindow == false)
   {
       (Resources["MoveToClose"] as Storyboard)?.Begin(this, false);
       (Resources["FlipArrowOpen"] as Storyboard)?.Begin(this, false);
   }
}
```

Comment: This pointed me in the correct direction and I got it functioning. I am curious though, how does this fit into the MVVM paradigm?

Comment: @Pants MVVM is a fancy name for "Three Tiered Design" with the view separated from the biz separated from the data layer. The dogma of MVVM leds one to think all has to be done in XAML. That is patently wrong. As long as one keeps the business logic on the VM and the view logic in XAML or code behind, that is MVVM. Just remember that XAML is parsed, turned into *code-behind* and linked; hence what one can do in XAML one can do in code-behind. Does one have to jump through hoops to get it all in XAML when ultimately it is integrated into code? :-) No. That's just my opinion, I could be wrong.

Comment: Interesting. I'm working on my first full-stack application and  keep seeing MVVM thrown around when talking about WPF. Your take on it makes a lot of sense to me. Anywho, thanks for your help!